# Prove that there are no integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ (x/y)^2 = 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rationality-testing

Prove that there are no $x$ and $y$ such that $(x/y)^2 = 2$

It says that I can assume that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime so I started the proof as:

- $x$ and $y$ relatively prime
- $\implies$ there are integer $m$ and $n$ s.t $mx + ny = 1$
- $\implies (m/n)^2 = ((1-ny)/(xn))^2$

I don't know what to do after this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is literally the same as asking if $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, and there's a plethora o proofs in this site: 
[Prove that square root of 2 is irrational using the principle of Mathematical Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183621/prove-that-square-root-of-2-is-irrational-using-the-principle-of-mathematical-in)

[square root of 2 irrational - alternative proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919681/square-root-of-2-irrational-alternative-proof)

And many more, use the search option.