# Irrational number $\sqrt2$ proof

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen the proof that  $\sqrt2$ is irrational
However I'm a bit confused. The proof goes something like this. first assume $m$ and $n$ are integers such that $$ \frac{m}{n}  = \sqrt{2} $$ $$ \frac{m^{2}}{n^{2}}  = 2 $$ $$m^{2}  = 2 n^{2}$$  $\implies m^{2} $ is divisible by $2 \implies m$ is divisible by 2. Let $2q = m$. Then $$m^{2}  = 4 q^{2} = 2n^{2}$$ $$ n^{2}  = 2 q^{2}$$ This means that $n^{2}$ is divisible by $2 \implies n$ is divisible by $2$...... Hence $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. $$$$If $ m^{2} $ is divisible by $2$ how do we know that $m$ is also divisible by $2$? If you say it's a prime number then I can argue that I didn't need to do all these steps. I could have just said that its factors don't multiply to $2$ hence $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Comment: because m is an integer. it $(m^2)$ cannot have only one multiple of $2$. it must have at least two multiple of $2$.

Comment: For the proof you also have to assume that $m$ and $n$ are co-prime, i.e. share no prime factors. You can do this because you otherwise could reduce the fraction. The square of an integer, say $N^2$, has the same distinct prime factors as $N$. The factors will just be an even multiple in the square.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917983/the-proof-of-sqrt2-is-not-rational-number-via-fundamental-theorem-of-arithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $m$ is odd, then $m=2k+1$, and thus
$$m^2=(2k+1)^2=2(2k^2+k)+1$$
and thus $m^2$ is odd too. That prove that if $m^2$ is even then $m$ is even too.

**You can generalize this result :** If a prime number $p\mid m^s$ for $s\in\mathbb N$ then $p\mid m$. Indeed, let $m=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_n^{\alpha_n}$ the decomposition of $m$ in prime factor. Then $$m^s=p_1^{s\alpha_1}...p_n^{s\alpha_n}$$
and thus all prime that divide $m^s$ also divide $m$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that if $m^2$ is even then $m$ is even, we proceed by contradiction. So suppose that $m$ is odd but $m^2$ is even. Then $m=2k+1$, so $m^2=4k^2 + 4k+1$. In particular, $m^2=4k(k+1)+1$ is one more than an even number, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above put it, you can get it by contradiction.

If you want to deal with the square root of a general prime $p$, you can use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: if $m^2$ is divisible by $p$, then it must have a prime factor of $p$, and all prime factors of $m^2$ are also prime factors of $p$.

To answer your last point: it is possible for a number to be a prime and still a product of two rational numbers $(3 = \tfrac{2}{1}\frac{3}{2})$.  The square roots are irrational, because you impose the condition that it must be the product of two equal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{m^2}{n^2}=2\implies m^2=2n^2\implies 2\mid m\implies 2\mid n \implies 2^2\mid m\implies 2^3\mid n$ etc...  so that $m$ and $n$ are each divisible by arbitrarily many $2$'s, an absurdity...

Or, assume $\frac mn$ is reduced,  then you get a contradiction when they are both divisible by $2$...

Answer (score -2):

Your entire proof is based on the **assumption** that `m` and `n` are integers. Till this assumption holds true. There is no fallacy in the argument.

But, Lets say `m` and `n` can be anything. That is, we don't assume anything for `m` and`n`. Then, your statement

> m^2 is divisible by 2 => m is divisible by 2

no longer holds true. for eg: m=k*sqrt(2).
 Then m is not divisible by 2. But m^2=2*k^2 is divisible by m.

Hence, by contradiction sqrt(2) is irrartional.

Comment: How do this answer the question?

Comment: Precisely $m$ and $n$ are integers, so that $m/n$ is rational and from there you can prove the contrapositive.