# Is this a correct proof of $r+\sqrt{2}\in\Bbb{Q}$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

My proof goes as follows:

Suppose that $r+\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then $r+\sqrt{2}=p/q\leftrightarrow2=(\dfrac{p-rq}{q})^2$. Hence $\dfrac{p-rq}{q} | 2$ thus $\dfrac{p-rq}{q}=2k$ where $k\in\Bbb{N}$. Therefore we have $2=(2k)^2=4k^2\leftrightarrow (k=\sqrt{1/2}\lor k=-\sqrt{1/2})$. Due to the contradiction $k\in\Bbb{N}\land k\notin\Bbb{N}$, we conclude that $r+\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: What is known about $r$?

Comment: It is known that $r\in\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Where did you write that in the question?

Comment: I didn't include it in the question.

Comment: Were we supposed to guess it?

Comment: Not at all. I just answered your question with the answer.

Comment: If $r + \sqrt 2 \in \Bbb Q$, then $\sqrt 2 \in \Bbb Q$, and we have reduced the problem to a classic case.

Comment: @RobertLewis Where does this implication follow from?

Comment: @Bright:  which implication?  That $\sqrt 2 \in \Bbb Q$ or that $\sqrt 2$ irrational?

Comment: @RobertLewis The implication that if $r+\sqrt{2}\in\Bbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt{2}\in\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Bright, rational numbers are closed under addition/subtraction, i.e. difference of two rationals is rational.

Comment: @Ennar Right...

Comment: @Bright  well, if $r + \sqrt 2 \in \Bbb Q$ then $\exists s \in \Bbb Q$ with $r + \sqrt q = s$; then since $r, s \in \Bbb Q$, we have $\sqrt 2 = s - r \in\Bbb Q$ since $\Bbb Q$ is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use this property:

> If $r+x\in\mathbb{Q}$ for $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ then also $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

From this it is easy to see that for your theorem it is sufficient to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, which is a well-known fact, that you can find here, for example [Irrational number $\sqrt2$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427806/irrational-number-sqrt2-proof).

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose that $r+\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then $r+\sqrt{2}=p/q\leftrightarrow2=(\dfrac{p-rq}{q})^2$. **Hence $\dfrac{p-rq}{q} | 2$**...

No, because you don't know that $\dfrac{p-rq}{q}$ is even an integer. It's just a rational number.

Comment: The square of $(p-rq)/q$ is divisible by 2 then $(p-rq)/q$ must be also divisible by 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bright $\frac34=2\frac38$, therefore $\frac34$ is divisible by $2$? Divisibility only makes sense for integers.

Comment: Right, good point.